# Sharepoint Security Trim control & its permission

Tags: 2007, development, security-trimming, security

We have a Custom List in SharePoint 2007, all authenticated users are allowed to add a new item into it.

Now, we have a page on which we are displaying the item details and it will be accessible for all the authenticated users. Now, we would like to display a control on that page and it should be visible only for the User who has created that item (should be hidden for rest the people)

We tried with SecurityTrim control however could not accomplish the task.

Do we have any specific permission that can be used with the SecurityTrim to accomplish this?

Comment: Could you create a webpart for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the Enterprise version, you can drop a filter on the page to filter the list by the current user.  If you don't have the enterprise version, you can create a view that is filter by Created by is equal to Me.  Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, I am not taking about the view.

It is a different page altogether, it just connect with the List and displays the Item details based on the given Item Id in the query string.

This is where we would like to introduce a securitytrimmed control to control the visibility of the Image is on the page.